# How to define dynamically, that some method of a class already exists in its base class? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, metaclass

I need to define either some method of a ChildClass overrides already existing method in BaseClass.
(Python 2.7)

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def method(self):
        pass

class ChildClass1(BaseClass):
    def method(self):
        pass

class ChildClass2(BaseClass):
    pass
```

The problem is that if I get list of methods for ChildClass1 and ChildClass2 (using dir() instruction, for example), the result is the same for both of them, because they both inherit from BaseClass.
Is there any way to define dymaically the difference between those cases?

Comment: `ChildClassN.method == BaseClass.method` (note that this only works on the class, not an instance)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found the solution. The required info resides in the `__dict__` member of any class, so even if  some SonClass inherits from some other, BaseClass, the only SonClass's members will present in the `__dict__` member, but not inherited members from the FatherClass!